# Views in storyboard get re-arranged when label has no text

Tags: ios, uilabel

I have two `labels` in my storyboard one on top the other using constraints. When the lower label has not text the top label gets 'bumped' down to where the first label was.

I don't want this behaviour. I want that in any case that the lower label should be a certain amount of height.

[image: image of issue]

How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

All I had to do was to set the height constraint on 'label 1' and it worked fine after that.

[image]